# How to debug plugin with custom message?

Tags: plugins, process, microsoft-dynamics

Is it possible to debug a plugin which Message is custom action using Plugin Registration tool?

Plugin registration tool -  Step:
[image: Update Existing Step]

Process:
[image: Process info]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have plugin been registerfeid against your custom Action. Install plugin profiler via Plugin registration tool and then you can start profiling. screenshot for reference.

Trigger your Action may it be from javascript or any other process and you will have trigger with it's context been catched.

Few articles for ref.

https://dynamics-chronicles.com/article/dynamics-365-different-ways-test-custom-actions

https://carldesouza.com/debugging-a-custom-workflow-activity-in-dynamics-365-and-powerapps/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am not sure how to have items in the list for Select Profile From CRM?

Comment: what do you mean? You will have to first install plugin profiler via plugin registration tool and then you will see the option of start profiling and so on.

Comment: please mark it as solved if it helps.